# What is the solution to this time complexity problem?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This problem is from Sara Baase's book, Computer Algorithms: Introduction to Design and Analysis.

Suppose algorithms A1 and A2 have worst-case time bound p and q, respectively. Suppose algorithm A3 consists of applying A2 to the output of A1. (the input for A3 is the input for A1.) give a worst-case time bound for A3.

Comment: `for(i=0 ; i<p ; i++) for(j=0 ; j<q ; j++) f()` what's that complexity?

Comment: Complexity is defined on size of input. This is almost like composition of functions. If an algorithm has complexity f(x) and now it's input is g(x), worst case time bound becomes : f( g(x) ). This is easy  and you should figure it out with hints. If you have doubts, please ask.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and i'm sorry if the question seemed lazy but i'm a complete novice and wasn't sure about the answer.